# How to change a Wordpress core DB function without editing core files?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have been fighting with this problem for several days now & I would appreciate input from (PHP / Wordpress) developers that are more experienced than me.

I'm making a debugging plugin for Wordpress, but one of the errors that I need to change comes from this file:
[/site/public/wp-includes/wp-db.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1344)

I need to change the structure and add more information to the `$error_str` in lines 1363 and 1366 so the output better suits our log reader and contains more useful information.

To do that I think I need to change the `print_error()` in line 1344

**The problems are:**

1. That the file is a core file in Wordpress, so I can't edit it directly.
2. It also have a global `$wpdb` variable that is used to call: `$wpdb->query()` & `$wpdb->get_row()` (also core functions in same file & class) that both in turn calls the `print_error()` function.
3. Other plugins are using these functions & I can't mess up their functionality but I should change their output too.

I think the most likely solution is to `inherit & override` the `print_error()` (and maybe also `query()` & `get_row()` so I can re-direct them to my new `print_error()`), but other plugins are using the `$wpdb` & `those functions`, I can (should) change the `error_log()` output for those plugins too, but I can't edit those plugins either & I can't mess them up with a faulty solution.

**Questions:**

- How can I replace the `print_error()`?
- What is the best way to do this?
- How do I deal with the global `$wpdb` variable?
- Do any of you have a better solution? I would very much appreciate it.

Link to the `print_error()` documentation (with source code):
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/print_error/

Link directly to the source code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1344

Comment: Please post your code here directly instead of linking to it.  All we need are the relevant parts related to your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @Justin They didn't "link to their code", but to the code of the CMS they are working with.

Comment: @Justin R, Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post my code since I'm under a NDA (non-disclosure agreement) contract and have to be careful with what I share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure this is an excellent idea, but you could extend the `wpdb` class and *replace* the global `$wpdb` object.

E.g.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb = new YourWpdbClass(); // you can override methods here to your heart's content
wp_set_wpdb_vars();
```

Officially, [the way to replace the global `$wpdb` is by creating a `db.php` file inside `wp-content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/). So if you plugin needs to alter db functionality it would need to include that file and possibly custom installation instructions

Comment: So inside `YourWpdbClass()` I put the overrided `print_error()` function? (Don't that thestroy the original `$wpdb` object? ) or do I put `print_error()` in `wp_set_wpdb_vars()`?

Comment: Your `YourWpdbClass` should extend `\wpdb`, and override the methods that you need to override. You'd obviously need to be careful not to break existing functionality, and possibly call the parent method directly.

Comment: @Sebastian Were you able to test this?

Comment: (Sorry for the delay) Yes & no, it kind of worked. It worked as long as the surrounding function were in scope, but when the function was finished it returned to it's original state, so I can only use this in my own functions where I override the `$wpdb`variable, but I can't catch errors from other plugins, example: `public static function surrounding_function() { global $wpdb; $wpdb = new YourWpdbClass(); //working } //not working`

Comment: Of course, it will only work if you define the $wpdb in the `db.php` file.